How to Log Deployment Events from Bamboo to Datadog Using Webhooks?
I’m trying to set up webhooks to log deployment events from my Bamboo to Datadog. The idea is to capture deployment information and link it with potential spikes in errors or performance issues.
I’ve come across these relevant documentation pages:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-webhooks-1018270680.html
https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/webhooks/
However, I can only find default options for build and deployment webhooks. How can I configure the webhooks to ensure deployment logs are properly sent to Datadog? Do I need any specific settings or customization to achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated!
